# Does a Breath Weapon count as a ranged attacks in association with feats?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, breath-weapon

Could I use a Feat like point blank shot for a breath weapon in Pathfinder?

Answer (score 6):

### No, breath weapons are area "attack" special abilities.

The details on [breath weapons](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules/#Breath_Weapon_Su) are available in the Universal Monster Rules. They are Su abilities and therefore require a default of a Standard Action to use (unless otherwise stated), deal area damage, and allow a Reflex Save. They do not provoke attacks of opportunity (as ranged attacks would) nor do they even require an attack roll.